# If $f$ is holomorph, injective and it's defined for all $z \neq 0$, then $f(z) = \alpha z$ or $f(z) = \frac{\alpha}{z}$, $\alpha \neq 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f: \mathbb{C} \setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is holomorph and injective then $f(z) = \alpha z$ or $f(z) = \frac{\alpha}{z}$, $\alpha \neq 0$.

All your observations are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement is true. By the Casorati–Weierstrass theorem, $f$ cannot have an essential singularity at $0$. Therefore, $f$ either has a pole or a removable singularity there. Applying the Casorati–Weierstrass theorem again, this time to $f\bigl(\frac1z\bigr)$, one deduces that the Laurent series of $f$ at $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ only has finitely many non-null terms. So, $f(z)=\frac{P(z)}{z^k}$, for some polynomial $P(z)$ and some $k\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$. If $P(z)$ is a constant $\alpha$, the injectivity of $f$ forces $k=1$. Otherwise, it follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra and from the injectivity of $f$ that $P(z)=\alpha(z-\beta)^m$. But, again from the injectivity of $f$ and also because $f$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, $\beta=0$, $m=1$ and $k=0$

Comment: Hm... how can $\beta=0$ if $P(0)\ne0$?